# How do I get basic statistics on a field in a joined table?

Tags: qgis, statistics

I have a shapefile to which I've joined a table, matching with an ID field. All the fields of the table show up correctly when I open the shapefile's attribute table. But when I go into vector/analysis tools/basic statistics I can only choose one of the fields in the shapefile itself; those I have joined are missing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've noticed joining fields in QGIS is limited in that if you want to make use of those newly added fields, for example in any query for sub-setting or in further geoprocessing/analysis workflows, the join usually has to be made permanent.

Because you're working with shapefiles, a new dataset might have to be created.

1. Join the data to your shapefile
2. Export the shapefile (right click and "Save As...") to a new file that can be used for what you need because the joined data is now part of the dataset

Comment: Thank you - that's not the most convenient process, but it works well.